# Iterate over object in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a problem using "each" helper to iterate over an object. I know that this should be pretty straightforward but after doing some reaserch I still don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have everything in a js file:

```
    var model = {
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Smith'
    };

    var source = '{{#each model}} \
        <p>Key: {{@key}}, Value: {{this}} &nbsp;</p> \
        {{/each}} '

    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var html = template(model);
```

When I check the value of the html variable it is an empty string. How do I get Handlebars to actually build the html I want?

EDIT:
Figured out the answer myself. Basically to use #each you have to have a named object in the model you are using with the template. This would work:

```
    var model = {
       person:{
              name: 'John',
              surname: 'Smith'
       }
    };

    var source = '{{#each person}} \
        <p>Key: {{@key}}, Value: {{this}} &nbsp;</p> \
        {{/each}} '

    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var html = template(model);
```

Comment: #each requires an array, does your json contain an array named model instead of an object?

Comment: according to the handlebars docs #each can also take objects: Additionally for object iteration, {{@key}} references the current key name:
`{{#each object}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}`
The first and last steps of iteration are noted via the @first and @last variables then iterating over an array. When iterating over an object only the @first is available.

Comment: Ok figured it out. Basically you have to have another object in the model to be able to iterate over it.